# CUDA\NUMBA Synchronization slower

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm new to CUDA, and I'm trying to speed up my code with NUMBA\CUDA.
However, I'm having some trouble because my code is really slow. An example code is here below.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit, guvectorize, int32, int64, float64
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit
def f_vec_loops(x, ret, maxiter):
    nx = len(ret)
    ny = len(ret[0])
    for k in range(maxiter):
        for i in range(nx):
            for j in range(ny):
                ret[i, j] += x[i, j]


x = 1024
y = 1024
a = np.ones([x, y], dtype='int32')
ret = np.zeros([x, y], dtype='int32')

a_cuda = cuda.to_device(a)
ret_cuda = cuda.to_device(ret)
maxiter = 100

s = timer()
cuda.synchronize()
f_vec_loops(a_cuda, ret_cuda, maxiter)
cuda.synchronize()

print(timer() - s)

s = timer()
trt = ret_cuda.copy_to_host()
print(trt)
print(timer()-s)
```

The output for is code is the subsequent:

```
24.132136431649194
[[100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 ...,
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]]
 0.03437229066477343
```

As you can see the resulting time is huge in relation to the complexity of the problem. I have tried to isolate the single GPU function and the resulting time is really small:

```
0.1956893293540045
```

And I achieved this taking off the "cuda.synchronize()", so in some way have to be connected to the synchronization of the threads.
However, I have no idea how to work around\solve this problem.
Any help is welcome!

Comment: Your CUDA kernel is completely serial and you are running one thread. There is no point in discussing performance in such a situation

Comment: As I said, I'm a newbie. Thank you for your answer and you time.

Answer (score 4):

There are two basic errors here -- your kernel is completely serial, and you are running one thread. The apparent speedup you see by removing `cuda.synchronize()` is only a result of changing what you are measuring. The kernel launch API is asynchronous, so removing the synchrionization call simply means you only measure the kernel launch time, not the total kernel execution time.

Your kernel could be trivially modified something like this:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit, guvectorize, int32, int64, float64
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import math

@cuda.jit
def f_vec_loops2(x, ret, maxiter):
    nx = len(ret)
    ny = len(ret[0])

    i, j = cuda.grid(2)
    if (i < nx) & (j < ny):
        value = 0
        for k in range(maxiter):
            value += x[i, j]

        ret[i, j] = value

@cuda.jit
def f_vec_loops(x, ret, maxiter):
    nx = len(ret)
    ny = len(ret[0])
    for k in range(maxiter):
        for i in range(nx):
            for j in range(ny):
                ret[i, j] += x[i, j]


x = 1024
y = 1024
a = np.ones([x, y], dtype='int32')
ret = np.zeros([x, y], dtype='int32')

a_cuda = cuda.to_device(a)
ret_cuda = cuda.to_device(ret)
maxiter = 100

s = timer()
f_vec_loops(a_cuda, ret_cuda, maxiter)
cuda.synchronize()
print(timer() - s)

threadsperblock = (16, 16)
blockspergrid_x = math.ceil(x / threadsperblock[0])
blockspergrid_y = math.ceil(y / threadsperblock[1])
blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)

s = timer()
f_vec_loops2[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](a_cuda, ret_cuda, maxiter)
cuda.synchronize()
print(timer() - s)

s = timer()
trt = ret_cuda.copy_to_host()
print(trt)
print(timer()-s)
```

When run you will see simething like:

```
In [2]: %run something.py
24.983618166297674
0.11915503349155188
[[100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 ..., 
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 ..., 100 100 100]]
0.002271135337650776
```

which provides about a 200x speedup compared to your original (completely serial) code.

The basic concepts of writing parallel code in CUDA are well described in books, tutorials, blogs, Stack Overflow questions, and in the toolkit documentation itself. The Numba Python CUDA language is very faithful reproduction of a subset of the basic CUDA C language and there are very low barriers to learning CUDA Python from CUDA C. All you need to do is some reading.

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said I'm really new to CUDA programming, and thank you very much for you help.